# Is there a way to reduce time complexity on the frontend with using Drupal json-api includes?

Tags: drupal, time-complexity, drupal-modules, json-api

I'm currently working with an output from the Drupal [json-api module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/filtering) and have noticed that the structure of an output forces an O(n^2) time complexity issue on the front by forcing the front end developers to reformat the json output given to them so an attachment can me in the same object as the entity it belongs to.

**Example**

So let's say I'm listing a bunch of categories with their thumbnails to be used on the front end. What a json output would normally look like for that is something like:

**Normal category json structure**

```
[
   {
      "uid":123,
      "category_name":"cars",
      "slug":"cars",
      "thumbnail":"example.com/cars.jpg"
   },
   {
      "uid":124,
      "category_name":"sports",
      "slug":"sports",
      "thumbnail":"example.com/sports.jpg"
   }
]
```

With drupal it seems that thumbnails are in their own includes separate from data creating an O(n^2). For example:

I make a get request using this endpoint:

`example.com/jsonapi/taxonomy_term/genre?fields[taxonomy_term--genre]=name,path,field_genre_image,vid&include=field_genre_image`

The structure of the data returned from the drupal json api module is going to be similar to this:

**pseudo code for better readability**

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "uid":123,
         "category_name":"cars",
         "slug":"cars",
         "relationships":{
            "thumbnail":{
               "id":123
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "uid":124,
         "category_name":"sports",
         "slug":"sports",
         "relationships":{
            "thumbnail":{
               "id":124
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "included":[
      {
         "type":"file",
         "id":123,
         "path":"example.com/cars.jpg"
      },
      {
         "type":"file",
         "id":124,
         "path":"example.com/sports.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

The problem with the drupal output is that I have to loop through the data and then in the data loop loop through the includes and attach each thumbnail to the category causing an O(n^2) on the frontend.

Is there a way for the frontend to request a category using the drupal json module to contain the thumbnail in the category like the normal json output above without having to restructure the json api on the frontend?

*Please note I am not a drupal developer so the terminology I might use will be off.*

Comment: Could you please double check the pseudo code you have posted? It doesn't look like a valid [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/) document. As far as I know Drupal's implementation of JSON:API is standard compliant. I expect that you have done some mistakes when creating that pseudo code.

Comment: @jelhan , I fixed the pseudocode. Do you mean Drupals JSON is compliant with JSON standards? Or is there a standard set by Drupal itself?

Comment: Maybe try a module that exports views as json like [Rest Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_views) or [JSONapi Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_views) so you can more easilt format the JSON the way you like.

Comment: @2pha, I'm the frontend dev for this project. Would that require an entire overhaul of api endpoints that are already using the json:api module or will those modules extend that module?

Comment: would need creation of the required views

Answer (score 0):

JSON:API can output a list of entities and includes another list of entities (can have different types). each entity has UUID, so, accessing them can be O(logn) or even O(0) if you apply index to their UUID

So, you would have one loop to parse each of the included entity and store and index them (like SQLite), or simply loop over all included entities, build 1 array key by UUID and value is object of an entity